# isinstance() returns false when the fully-qualified object class differs from the qualified class

Tags: python, python-2.7

When a 3rd party library method uses `isinstance()` to compare an object with a class, it returns `False` because it compares the fully qualified class name of the object with a qualified class name that starts "higher" up.

E.g.: `isinstance()` finds that the object class and classname differ:

Expected:

> 'network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage'

Found:

> '**backend**.network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage'

and returns `False` given the code snippet:

```
if not isinstance(value, self.type):
      raise ValidationError('Expected type %s for field %s, '
                            'found %s (type %s)' %
                            (self.type, name, value, type(value)))
```

Is there a way to change the fully qualified name of a class (at least temporarily)?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are actually calling `isinstance`?  Maybe try to put together some minimal example code ... It _looks_ like you're expecting to be able to check based on a fully qualified string path of some sort, but that's not how `isinstance` works.

Comment: `isinstance` doesn't compare for class equality. Perhaps `is` may be better suited for your needs?

Comment: Thanks, I revised my question to make it clearer.  I added a code snippet.

Comment: Have you considered that these could just be completely different classes? Changing the class name won't help; that'd be like declaring that all guns are now called "sodas" and expecting them to be delicious when you stick one in your mouth.

Comment: Thanks, user235*.  I don't think they are different classes.  Interesting analogy...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as Python is concerned, the classes `network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage` and `backend.network.mhistory.service.mhistory_messages.MHistoryActivityViewMessage` are not the same. That's true even if they have exactly the same definition because they were read from the same file!

Your bug isn't that `isinstance` is returning the "wrong" answer, it's that you're able to access those two classes (and possibly others as well) by two different names.

There are likely two different problems leading to the bug. First, you've probably got some code somewhere that is messing around with `sys.path`. That isn't inherently bad, but it's causing you problems by making the contents of your `backend` package available two differnet ways, first directly (e.g. `import network`) and via `backend` (`from backend import network`). You don't want this.

The second part of your bug (which may have been the motivating factor leading to the first part), is that you're actually *using* both ways of accessing those objects. You only need one, and should thus fix the parts that import the package the wrong way.

Comment: Interesting theory.  +1.

Comment: Thank you very much, Blckknght.  I think your theory makes a lot sense, and I will look into those issues that you brought up.

Comment: how to debug to confirm that's the real issue?

Comment: @ZhengGao: The question has some useful code to print out the types of objects that it thinks *should* have the same type, but which don't. I suppose another troubleshooting step that could help you identify if you're having this issue is to look at `sys.path` and see what directories have been added to it. If more than one directory inside your project are in the path, the code might be using two different names for the same modules, which was the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

For it to return True, the first argument to `isinstance` must be an *instance* of the second.  Providing the same class for both arguments results in a False:

```
>>> isinstance( int, int)
False
>>> isinstance( int(1), int)
True
```

Here, `int` is a class and a class is not an instance of a class.

`int(1)`, by contrast, is an integer (an instance of `int`).  Consequently, the second example returns True.

#### Name qualification

Let's compare `isinstance` when applied to qualified and unqualified names:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from numpy import bool
>>> isinstance( numpy.bool, bool)
False
>>> isinstance( bool, numpy.bool)
False
>>> isinstance( bool(1), numpy.bool)
True
>>> isinstance( numpy.bool(1), bool)
True
```

Name qualification does not affect the result.

Comment: Thanks, I've revised my original question to make it clearer.  The issue is that the fully-qualified class name of the object has a different prefix from the qualified class name.  But I'm not sure why it is the case.

Comment: @morfys I would try to reproduce the problem that you see but there are still items that I would need that are missing from the question.

Comment: Thank you, John1024.  I will think about how to construct a clearer example.